# Using .join() with list comprehension to join prefix onto every word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

I would like to join a prefix to every word in a list. like so:

```
mywords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
['prefix'.join(word) for word in mywords]
```

If I run this, every letter in word has the prefix. Is there a way to ensure that I get

```
['prefixword1', 'prefixword2' etc.]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to use `join()`, then:

```
["".join(["prefix", word]) for word in mywords]
```

But please note that you could also do it **with a simple string concatenation**:

```
["prefix" + word for word in mywords]
```

Or, using f-strings:

```
[f"prefix{word}" for word in mywords]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation here.

```
['prefix'+word for word in mywords]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the 'join()' method for that.

```
prefix = 'some_string'

[prefix + i for i in mywords]
```

Comment: Why the `enumerate`?

Comment: his example has 1 and 2

Comment: It looks like the OP doesn't add suffixes to the words. This produces `['prefixword11', 'prefixword22']`, which seems to add unnecessary complexity .

Comment: @NicolasGervais nope: you added a static prefix and the iteration index as suffix, but it appears the op needs only the prefix. that's why folks wonder about the enumerate ...